# Calculating sum of digits in a number, incorrect result when using / and %

Tags: python, math, python-3.x

i am practising on Project Euler and I am working on a problem to calculate the sum of digits in `2 ** 1000` (2 ^ 1000) in Python. My code

```
z = 2 ** 1000
print(z)

sum = 0
while z > 0:
    x = int(z % 10)
    sum += x
    z = z / 10

print(sum)
```

gives the result

```
10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376
1189
```

While Python is able to calculate right value for z, the sum of digits in z is wrong. Why is the sum not correct?

Comment: Python 2.7 and 3.3 give you different results. Python 2 gives sum as 1366 and Python 3 as 1189. That's because Python 3 return 0.1 from 1/10, and Python 2 return 0

Comment: No, it is because the float conversion loses precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly Python 2.7 and 3.3 give different results. 2.7 gives the sum of digits as `1366` and 3.3 `1189`. While your program is correct on Python 2.7, you must remember that [the semantics of `/` have changed in Python 3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/), and the integer division operator on Python 3 is `//`; otherwise your divide by 10 converts the number into float (and **loses precision**). Thus

```
z = 2**1000
sum = 0
while z > 0:
    x = int(z % 10)
    sum += x
    z //= 10
print(sum)
```

Python 2.6 and 2.7 can also use the new division operators by enabling them using

```
from __future__ import division
```

in the beginning of each file.

Comment: Because Python 3.3 return 0.1 for `1/10`, while Python 2.7 return 0.

Comment: It amazes me that Python makes such drastic changes to a fundamental operator such as / as if it were some newly born language.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, hope this question helps other beginners

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: the behavior is available already in python 2.6 if you enable it, with `from __future__ import division`. Also, Python 3 does the right thing.

Comment: @Antti Haapala, that doesn't excuse the fact that they changed the default behavior of the operator after about 18 years!

Comment: It is explained in the document, sometimes a default is wrong, and you can be wrong for 18 years, it does not mean that you should not change your way after 18 years.

Comment: @Antti Haapala, if the Python creators were more thoughtful they wouldn't have this mess where it takes years for libraries to port over to Python 3. I can imagine many scientific libraries requiring changes and much testing because of the change in the / operator. Python needs to grow up.

Comment: It is exactly the scientific libraries that return wrong results because of the old division operator, when passed in an int.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating  sum, would it not be ideal to change change sum's value to x completely, so write sum=x instead of sum+=x

Comment: Wouldn't that leave `sum` as the last `x` examined?  In this case, the leading digit of `z`?